# Specify [mysqld] in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This is my configMap. I'm trying to specify [mysqld] config, but when I use this file alone with

```
helm upgrade -i eramba bitnami/mariadb --set auth.rootPassword=eramba,auth.database=erambadb,initdbScriptsConfigMap=eramba,volumePermissions.enabled=true,primary.persistence.existingClaim=eramba-storage --namespace eramba-1 --set mariadb.volumePermissions.enabled=true
```

I don't see the specified configurations in my db pod; however, I do see the c2.8.1.sql file applied tho.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eramba
  namespace: eramba-1
data:
  my.cnf: |-
    [mysqld] 
    max_connections = 2000
    sql_mode=""
    max_allowed_packet="128000000"
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout="200"
  c2.8.1.sql: |
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS erambadb;
    #create user 'erambauser'@'eramba-mariadb' identified by 'erambapassword';
    #grant all on erambadb.* to 'erambauser'@'eramba-mariadb';
    #flush privileges;
    USE erambadb;
    #
    # SQL Export
    # Created by Querious (201067)
    # Created: 22 October 2019 at 17:39:48 CEST
    # Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)
    #
    
    SET @PREVIOUS_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    .....
```

Comment: You provided `initdbScriptsConfigMap=eramba2` for `helm upgrade`, but name of ConfigMap is `eramba`. It's not a mistake?

Comment: Yea this is a mistake. It should be eramba, sorry. I did deploy the initdbScriptsConfigMap as eramba tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [values.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mariadb/values.yaml) file for MariaDB helm chart, you can see 3 types of ConfigMap:

- initdbScriptsConfigMap - to supply Init scripts to be run at first boot of DB instance
- primary.existingConfigmap - to control MariaDB Primary instance configuration
- secondary.existingConfigmap - to control MariaDB Secondary instance configuration

Thus, each of them is intended for the specific purpose and it is not a good idea to mix these settings in one ConfigMap.

I recommend you to create new ConfigMap eramba2 for custom `my.cnf` with all necessary values (not only new) as below.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: eramba2
      namespace: eramba-1
    data:
      my.cnf: |-
        [mysqld]
        skip-name-resolve
        explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
        max_connections = 2000
        sql_mode=""
        innodb_lock_wait_timeout="200"
        basedir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb
        plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin
        port=3306
        socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
        tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp
        max_allowed_packet=128000000
        bind-address=::
        pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
        log-error=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/logs/mysqld.log
        character-set-server=UTF8
        collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    
        [client]
        port=3306
        socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
        default-character-set=UTF8
        plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/plugin
    
        [manager]
        port=3306
        socket=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
        pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysqld.pid
```

Create eramba2 ConfigMap:

```
kubectl create -f eramba2.yaml
```

And then create MariaDB with helm using new ConfigMap eramba2:

```
helm upgrade -i eramba bitnami/mariadb --set auth.rootPassword=eramba,auth.database=erambadb,initdbScriptsConfigMap=eramba,volumePermissions.enabled=true,primary.persistence.existingClaim=eramba-storage,mariadb.volumePermissions.enabled=true,primary.existingConfigmap=eramba2 --namespace eramba-1
```

Connect to pod:

```
kubectl exec -it eramba-mariadb-0 -- /bin/bash
```

Check my.cnf file:

```
cat /opt/bitnami/mariadb/conf/my.cnf
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you sir!